# Quantum Mechanics - Hidden Variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-interpretations

In Steven Weinberg's Lecture on Quantum Mechanics (p. 342), he writes:

> The correlation between the spins of the two particles can be
>   expressed as the average value of the product of the $\hat{a}$
>   component of the spin of particle 1 and the $\hat{b}$ component of the
>   spin of particle 2:
>
> $\langle (\textbf{s1} \cdot \hat{a}) (\textbf{s2} \cdot \hat{b})
>  \rangle = -\frac{\hbar^2}{4} \int{d\lambda\ \rho(\lambda) S(\hat{a},
>  \lambda) S(\hat{b}, \lambda)}$
>
> where $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are any two unit vectors.
>
> In quantum mechanics, we have:
>
> $\langle (\textbf{s1} \cdot \hat{a}) (\textbf{s2} \cdot \hat{b})
>  \rangle = -\frac{\hbar^2}{4} \hat{a} \cdot \hat{b}$
>
> There is no obstacle to constructing a function $S$ and a probability
>   density $\rho$ for which are equal for any single pair of directions
>   $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$.

Can someone explain to me precisely how this is done and what $S(\hat{a}, \lambda)$ and $\rho(\lambda)$, along with the hidden variables $\lambda$ would be?

My guess is that since we want something that is rotationally invariant since it depends only on the dot product, we want some $S$ and hidden variables $\lambda$ that act nicely under rotations.

On the other hand, since the first equation is a local hidden variable theory, I thought this was not possible by Bell's inequalities...

Comment: I edited it to try and make it clear which parts are quoted from Weinberg and which parts are your own text - but I'm not 100% sure I got it right - can you check?

Answer (score 3):

You should read [Bell's original paper](http://philoscience.unibe.ch/documents/TexteHS10/bell1964epr.pdf), where he constructs such a model explicitly.  The key point is that for any **single pair** of directions one can construct such a model. Bell's theorem states that there is no single local hidden variable model that can reproduce the quantum mechanical correlation for **every pair** of directions.

(If you are interested in reading more about ontological models, see also [Harrigan and Spekkens](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2661) and [Lewis et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6554).)